# Can you interface 2 gigabit ethernet ports via one rgmii interface?

Tags: ethernet, gigabit, rgmii

Can we use the KSZ9893RNXC from Microchip as the Ethernet PHY chip, and interface the 2 gigabit ports to Allwinner H6, which has only one RGMII interface. Also please note that we are aiming at using the 2 gigabit ports simultaneously.

KSZ9893RNXC
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/KSZ9893RNXC?qs=qpJ%252B%252B%252Bdg6p1h38Qq3AER7g%3D%3D

Allwinner H6
https://linux-sunxi.org/H6

Comment: Without studying the specific parts you listed, in general, no, you need a MAC for each simultaneously active PHY. You'd need either a dual-MAC SOC or add a switch chip.

Comment: Note that there are 3-port GBit Ethernet switch chips with integrated PHY for just this purpose. The KSZ9893 from Microchip is one example of the type of chip you need. However, you will need to configure it, so watch out for driver support.